# Score short quote in text with Python

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp, fuzzywuzzy

## Background

Using Python, I need to score the existence of a quote, containing around 2-7 words, a longer text. The quote doesn't have to match the text precisely, but similar words should have the *same order*.

For example, given the following **long text**:

> The most beautiful things in the world cannot be seen or touched, they are felt with the heart

The following quotes should be scored **high** (say, above 80 / 100):

> The beautiful thing in our world
>
> World cannot see
>
> They feel with the heart

Since they are not precise, but they preserve the order.

While, on the other hand, these quotes should be scored **lower** (say, below 50 / 100):

> The beautiful heart cannot be felt or seen
>
> They are the most seen in the world
>
> These words don't even appear on this text

Because (the first 2) appear entirely in the text, but do not preserve the order.

## The problem

This task cannot be accomplished by simply checking the existence of each word in the text. I don't know which algorithm fits best for this task.

## What I have tried

Most of the functions in `fuzzywuzzy` (`partial_token_sort_ratio`, `token_sort_ratio` and etc) scored the later terms higher.
`partial_ratio` did score the earlier terms higher, but the quote

> These words don't even appear on this text

Got 52 / 100 which is unreasonably high.

## My question

How can I use python to score the existence of short quotes in longer texts as mentioned above?

Comment: You might have better luck on the Data Science stack exchange, since this isn't really a coding issue.

Comment: I added `algorithm` as that seems to be your main blocking point.

Comment: This sounds like [plagiarism detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism_detection), have you looked into such algorithms to see how real life systems score texts against each other?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can break through your barrier by adapting the [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem.  In your case, the subsequence would refer to word position, effectively defining "increase" as "appears later in the original phrase".  You could modify that by lightly rewarding other words that appear in the quotation.

For instance, given your text

```
The most beautiful things in the world cannot be seen or touched, they are felt with the heart
```

Let's score the two quotations

```
The beautiful thing in our world
The beautiful heart cannot be felt or seen
```

These will code to the text's word positions:

```
The beautiful thing in our world
 1      3       4    5  -1   7

The beautiful heart cannot be felt or seen
 1      3       18     8    9  15  11  10
```

The first one has an increasing sequence of 6 words out of a total of 7 over a range (in the text) of 7, and a picayune personal pronoun missing.  The second has an increasing sequence of 5 words, "The beautiful cannot be seen" (take the nearest), out of 8 words over a range of 10, and three "regressions" (order inversions).

From here, I expect that you could either write your own evaluation function from a handful of examples, or simply choose a few feature-defining functions and fit a simple model to scores you supply as "ground truth" labels.  I see

- percentage of words in sequence
- total percentage matched
- words matched as percentage of match range (i.e. 5/10 for the second quotation)
- missing words (penalty)
- present words out of sequence (small context bonus).

Is that enough to get you moving?

Comment: This solution might potentially have too many implications for me right now. Maybe when I have some time for improvement, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open-ended problem so I'll try to add some ideas that may be helpful to get the ball rolling. They overlap with what you're trying but may add some insight.

You might want to make use of WordNet ([NLTK has an interface](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html)) to identify words in an equivalence class (e.g. "felt" ~ "feel", and "thing" ~ "things", where ~ represents word equivalence).

As you try to get better accuracy, you'll find it gets complicated as "felt" could be a noun or a verb. In the noun case "felt" is not ~ to "feel" and in the verb case it is (being the past tense of "feel"). Additionally, for a short sub string, it's more difficult for a part of speech tagger to figure out what part of speech a word is. In any case, you should be able to find equivalent word by doing a search through WordNet with NLTK ([WordNet entry for "felt"](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=felt&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=00000)).

Once you are able to identify words from your sub-string in your target string, you can proceed in several ways, some of which you have mentioned.

I'd suggest also looking at something resembling a minimum edit distance algorithm for your problem. You'd want to support operations such as insertion of words, removal of words, swapping of words, and equivalent word substitution; and you'd want to penalize things like word swaps, and missing words from the longer quote. The idea would be to try and transform the short quote to match up as a sub-string in the longer quote.

For example:

> The most beautiful things in the world cannot be seen or touched, they
>   are felt with the heart

1) "World cannot see" has edit distance 1 because you have to to add "be" to the substring to match the target string.

2) "The beautiful heart cannot be felt or seen" has edit distance say 10.5 (if you see a smaller edit distance, replace it with that one :))

- add "most" (+1)
- remove "heart" (+1)
- remove "in the world" (+3)
- swap "felt" and "seen" (+5 see below)
- identify "felt" with "touched" (+0.5 see below)

Here I took the liberty of assigning score .5 to identify words that weren't exactly the same and a penalty of 5 for word swaps. I didn't penalize for missing words. See [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) which talks about swaps for an implementation that you can start with.

Comment: This solution might potentially have too many implications for me right now. Maybe when I have some time for improvement, I will try it.